# Find values not present in supplied list postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to find a query that will tell me the values that are not in my database. 
Eg:

```
      select seqID, segment from flu where seqID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).
```

Now if my database doesn't have seqID's 3,8,9 how would I find/display only the missing seqID's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions based on your code. You seem to need an EXCEPT statement.  The following code was developed on PostgreSQL 9.1.

```
create temp table my_value(seq_id int);

insert into my_value(seq_id) values
(1), (2), (4), (5), (6), (7);

select unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
EXCEPT 
select distinct seq_id from my_value;
```

I'm assuming that you are have a hard coded list of ints (like in your example in the question).  I just created a temp table for testing and demo purposes, but I'm sure you can make the necessary adjustments to work in your situation.  If you don't have a hard-coded list of ints, then you just need to do a select again whatever source would contain it.

Answer (score 8):

```
with idlist (id) as (
   values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
)
select l.id as missing_seq_id
from idlist l
  left join flu f on f.seqID = l.id
where f.seqID is null;
```

Comment: Do you think this would be more/less efficient than an EXCEPT.  Seems like it would be less, but I'm curious to your thoughts.  I have found that your answers usually are very good.  :)

Comment: @DavidS: I don't think it will make a difference. But the only way to tell is by looking at the execution plan when doing it with real data.

Comment: Yeah, I went back and looked at my and tried to dummy something up with yours.  It's hard to tell because with such small samples sizes its hard to tell.  Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a well known issue with using EXCEPT, etc.  Again, you are one of the guys that always seems to give really good answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this without having all of the possible digits stored in some table (or just 0-9, and use cross joins for higher numbers).  You can't select ID's or numbers that don't exist in data.  If you made the other table, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT newID
FROM newTable nt
LEFT JOIN flu f ON f.seqID = nt.newID
          AND f.seqID NOT IN (SELECT * from newTable)
```

newID would be the column name for your newly made table that holds the values.
newTable is the name of the new Table you would make to store the values.

Comment: It's possible with temporary tables.